# Chainlink NFT: Unable to update Metadata on Rinkeby Opensea

Tags: smartcontracts, chainlink, openzeppelin

Hi I was was trying out the Chainlink Dynamic Truffle NFT project following along the video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EzZEx0lumr0&t=224s

The goal of this contract is to use the VRF random number generator and then create random characters.

I redeployed my contract and funded it with LINK token manually.
(At some point I'll need to automate this process but I was running into compile errors as the chainlink Git repo wouldn't compile with solidity ^0.8.0. If you have a repo where you've done think, please send me a link and I'd appreciate it.)

Here's the verified deployed contract on Rinkeby
[Rinkeby Contract][1]
Contract addr: 0x70f3e5b8a669531cacce7be616d5449a0f8e178b

I created TokenId#0 was some random attributes (see below) and it pops up on Opensea testnet.

Token#0 shows up on Opensea's test net and has the following attributes.

https://testnets.opensea.io/assets/0x70f3e5b8a669531cacce7be616d5449a0f8e178b/0

I then uploaded the metadata on IPFS desktop, and manually set the tokenURI on my smart contract on Rinkeby. I also confirmed that I can read back the correct tokenURI for token#0.

https://ipfs.io/ipfs/QmRFeyhY1xU9PY3HCG2fBpjca4wfh8R93rKCDFquL8eHX8?filename=the-chainlink-knight.json

The IPFS image source:
https://ipfs.io/ipfs/QmZGQA92ri1jfzSu61JRaNQXYg1bLuM7p8YT83DzFA2KLH?filename=Chainlink_Knight.png

This is when I assumed that OpenSea would update the metadata and display the image and attributes, but it's been several hours and it's still just blank.
Do I need to wait longer or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks for your help.

[ characters(uint256) method Response ]
strength   uint256 :  14
dexterity   uint256 :  70
constitution   uint256 :  25
intelligence   uint256 :  83
wisdom   uint256 :  89
charisma   uint256 :  40
experience   uint256 :  0
name   string :  "The Chainlink Knight"]

Answer (score 0):

If you go here:
https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0x70f3e5b8a669531cacce7be616d5449a0f8e178b#readContract

Then call tokenURI for id 0

[image: etherscan page]

You can see it's empty.